# Specifying a route name in Redirect::intended

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I would like to get a route value by its name and store it in a variable.

The reason being, I would like to use the Redirect::intended($url) method to redirect the user to a route instead of just putting the url there.

Basically, I would like to have the same behavior as with Redirect::route($route_name) but with the intended() function.

Is there a method like Route::getValueByName() ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want to pass current route name as a default for `intended` ?

Comment: Say I have the following route: Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'BaseController@index']);
I'd like to use Redirect::intended('home')

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I get you right, you could just use

```
Redirect::intended(route('home'));
```

**OR**

```
Redirect::intended('/');
```

**OR EVEN**

```
Redirect::intended(action('BaseController@index'));
```